# Variance & Joint Density Function

Tags: probability, statistics

$X$ and $Y$ have joint density given by $$f_{XY}(x,y)=\begin{cases}2,& 0≤x≤y≤1 \\0,& \text{elsewhere}\end{cases}$$ a) Find $\text{Var}(Y|X=x_0)$.

b) What is the answer if $x_0$ is not in the interval $[0,1]$?

So I know that if the $x_0$ is not in the interval, then the answer is $0$, right? I need help finding the variance.

Comment: Are you sure? The integration of $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$ over the domain give you $2$, and you should get $1$ instead.

Comment: yeah it is equal to 2

Comment: Suppose this is true, then $f_{X}(x)$ would be $2$, and $\int f_{X}(x)=2$ as well. This does not make sense to me.

Comment: @Bombyxmori It is also $x<y$, not $0<x,y<1$.

Comment: I see. Did not notice this condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $0\le x \le y \le 1$ you have that $$f_{Y|X}(y|x)=\dfrac{f_{XY}(x,y)}{f_X(x)}=\frac{2}{\int_{x}^{1}f_{XY}(x,y)dy}=\dfrac{2}{\int_{x}^{1}2dy}=\dfrac{1}{1-x}$$ for all $x\le y \le 1$. That is $Y|X=x$ is uniformly distributed in $[x,1]$. Thus $$Var(Y|X=x)=\frac{(1-x)^2}{12}$$

Comment: this made a lot of sense, thank you

Comment: you are welcome mate

Answer (score 2):

It suffice to compute
$$
f_{Y|X}(y|x)=\frac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{f_{X}(x)}=\frac{2*\chi{0\le x\le y\le 1}}{\int^{1}_{x}2dy *0\le x\le y\le 1}=\frac{1}{1-x}*\chi{0\le x\le y\le 1}
$$
Therefore as a function of $y$, $f_{Y|X}(y|x)$ is well defined on $0\le x\le y\le 1$ except at $y=1,x=1$. Excluding this case we may compute that
$$
Var(Y|X=x_{0})=\frac{(1-x_0)^{2}}{12}, x_{0}\not=1
$$
and for $x_{0}\not \in [0,1]$ the conditional distribution itself is not properly defined.

Comment: @Bombyx, why is (1−x_0)^2 in the denominator and not the numerator

Comment: @abcxyz: yeah I was mistaken.